# Asterisk Trying to play back audio file "File /path/to/file.wav does not exist in any format"

Tags: asterisk

i'm trying to rig an application to send out premade calls.

I'm trying to get asterisk to play back wav/mp3/gsm files (I compiled it with the proper extensions and they're loaded)

but when ever I try to play back a file, I get

```
-- Executing [_A.@cnsout:3] Playback("SIP/172.20.0.15-00000003",      "/var/media/derp.gsm") in new stack
[Jul 24 14:01:16] WARNING[8853][C-00000003]: file.c:774 ast_openstream_full: File /var/media/derp.gsm does not exist in any format
[Jul 24 14:01:16] WARNING[8853][C-00000003]: file.c:1247 ast_streamfile: Unable to open /var/media/derp.gsm (format (ulaw)): No such file or directory
[Jul 24 14:01:16] WARNING[8853][C-00000003]: app_playback.c:494 playback_exec: Playback failed on SIP/172.20.0.15-00000003 for /var/media/derp.gsm
```

I've tried everything from converting the file to gsm, 8000k mono wav, raw pcm, saving it to the /var/lib/asterisk/sounds folder etc.

Comment: Have you done the most obvious and put the file in `/var/media` like it shows? And made sure the asterisk user has access to the file?

Comment: Yes. 

I've also tried putting the file in /var/lib/asterisks/sounds and sounds/en

Comment: I’m not understanding where you are getting all these different paths from. I mean, it’s looking for the file in one place. Put the file there and it will work. Is Asterisk chrooted? That would effect the relative path you have to put the file in. But it’s pretty clear it’s looking for the file in /var/media.

Comment: I've been passing /var/media/file_name to astrisk and its failing. I tried playing the file in /var/lib/asterisk/sounds as well and passing it as just "file_name".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read carefully documentation

Asterisk is multi-format/codec pbx. You should put filename **without extension**, asterisk will choose best format for current codec

For example you can have

```
file.gsm
file.g729
file.sln
```

If you call via ulaw, will be choosed sln, via g729 - .g729 etc.